# How can I import ObjectId from the bson package into Apache Beam pipeline (that is compatible with pymongo)?

Tags: pymongo, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, bson

Hi I'm working on a pipeline in google Dataflow that loads some MongoDB documents (with pymongo) and process it. At some point I need to cast an id to a MongoDB ObjectId.
To cast it I use the bson package, the problem is that with the dataflowRunner is not detecting the package, and I don't understand why because I declared pymongo[srv] in setup.py.
If I declare bson in the setup.py I get an error because the installed bson dependency is not compatible with pymongo.
I know that pymongo comes with its own bson package but how can I make it available inside an Apache Beam pipeline?

Comment: What (code) have you tried? What errors were reported?

Comment: A snippet of your setup.py would also be helpful.